# Trying to figure out how to use regular expressions with an input that has a time

Tags: regex

Basically, I want users to input a time in a specific format: mm:ss. I'm attempting to use regular expressions to ensure this happens. See below:

```
System.out.print("Enter time (mm:ss): ");
String time = scan.nextLine();
String regex = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";
while(!time.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.print("Please enter time in the correct format (mm:ss): ");
    time = scan.nextLine();
}
String[] timeArray = time.split(":");
```

I'm just confused if I'm using .matches() correctly here, or if my regex String will just be interpreted as a string and not parameters requiring two integers with a length of 2, separated by a colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using `matches()` correctly, but your regex is not correct.

Your regex would allow `99:99`, which is not a valid time.

To match a valid time, ie `00:00` through `59:59`, use this regex:

```
String regex = "[0-5]\\d:[0-5]\\d";
```

Note: `\d` means “a digit”, ie same as `[0-9]`.

Also note that for `matches()` to return `true`, the regex must match the *entire* string.